# With Passport, what is the purpose of serializing a user if i'm authenticating with tokens?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, oauth-2.0, passport-google-oauth2

I'm using `passport-google-oauth20` as the sole form of authentication for my app. Everything seems fine, and I'm able to authenticate a user and store him in the DB with the `verify` callback passport provides.

In this app, I will only use google to authenticate the user and check if he exists or not in the DB. I won't be making more requests to google, or grabbing more information from google.

I notice there's a lot of magic that happens behind the passport's callback function. I have a vague understanding of how `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` works, but I'm not sure *when* it's necessary.

The callback function that passport provides, sets a JWT on localStorage, so do I still need to serialize a user even if I set the option of `{ session: false }` on the redirect?

Here's some code to clear things up

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/redirect'
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        // console.log('TCL: profile', profile); -> Gives profile info
        // console.log('TCL: refreshToken', refreshToken); -> Null
        // console.log('TCL: accessToken', accessToken); 
        // This attaches the user profile to the req object
        done(null, profile);
    })
);
```

Here are the routes:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.get(
    '/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] })
);

app.get(
    '/auth/google/redirect',
    passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.user);
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
```

I'm able to get the profile and all the information I need. Do I still need to serialize the user?

Answer (score 1):

serializeUser and deserializerUser functions are used for setting cookie and reading that cookie.

In google oauth when a user first sign in with google account, you reach its profile and find a uniquely identifying property to save in the database. That identifying property should be the profile.id. So you store the user's profile.id in the database.

Next time, when user logs in, you need to identify the user, otherwise you will be saving the same profile.id over and over again. In order to remember user, you create cookies. When user logs in, you grab that profile.id and query  if that profile.id is saved in the database. this operation done in the passport callback function and if user exists, passport will have access to that user.

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
clientID:keys.googleClientID,
clientSecret:keys.googleClientSecret,
callbackURL:"/auth/google/callback"}, (accessToken,refreshToken, profile,done)=>{
     User.findOne({googleId:profile.Id}).then((user)=>{
        if(user){ //it checks if the user is saved in the database
            done(null,user)
        }else {
            new User({googleId:profile.id}).save().then((user)=>done(null,user))
        }
     })   
}))
```

As soon as passport.js has access to the user, it automatically calls the serializeUser function, gets a uniquely identifying property for the user, which is user.id, and injects it into the cookie, and that cookie is sent to the client in the response header.

```
passport.serializeUser((user,done)=>{
//user.id is not profile id. it is id that created by the database
    done(null,user.id)
})
```

once the browser receives the response, it saves the cookie in a file and when it makes follow up requests to the same server, it will automatically appends that cookie in the request. Passport.js is going to pull that uniquely identifying info which is user.id and pass it to the database and database will identify the client.

```
passport.deserializeUser((id,done)=>{
    User.findById(id).then((user)=>{
        done(null,user)
    })
})
```